# sed: Delete all characters until first alphanumeric character

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I have input that looks like:

```
    -|+ string1
   IAmString2-OrAmI\ \   \
\ - 3string3+string4
```

I want the output to be:

```
string1
IAmString2-OrAmI\ \   \
3string3+string4
```

In other words, I want to read the beginning of the string until I come across an alphanumeric character, then print out the rest of the string from that character forwards regardless of its contents.

I came closest with:

```
sed -n 's/[[:alnum:]]/&\n/;s/.*\n//p'
```

But that deleted up to *and including* the first alphanumeric character, so I got output that looked like:

```
tring1
AmString2-OrAmI\ \  \
string3+string4
```

Any ideas?  I am open to anything that would work from a bash script.

Comment: I wonder why this got downvoted? It has clear requirements, sample input, expected output, and an attempted solution. What more could we ask for? Upvoting to counter.

Comment: The question clearly shows research effort and clearly explains the problem so I'm upvoting too. It's refreshing to see new users ask good questions. Welcome, Richard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/^[^[:alnum:]]*//' file
string1
IAmString2-OrAmI\ \   \
3string3+string4
```

Comment: Jeebus.  Do you know, I tried this except I forgot the asterisk.  Thanks, Ed.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re using GNU sed, the following should work:

```
sed 's/^\W*//'
```

This anchors the expression at the start of the line and matches zero or more successive non-**W**ord characters, replacing them with an empty string. Note that *word* characters include all alphanumeric characters – and underscores. So, unfortunately, this won’t work if there are underscores among the non-alphanumeric characters at the start (thanks, Ed).

I find the above syntax to be easier to type (and remember) but it's not POSIX compatible (portable to other systems) like Ed's answer.

Comment: @EdMorton Well spotted. I had forgot that the underscore character is also considered as a *word* character. I'll add that proviso to my answer. Thanks.